# How to insert specific date format for Date in mongoDB with pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I simply need one of my collections to have a TTL index.

The documentation states that i should do something like this :

> db.log_events.insert( {
> "expireAt": new Date('July 22, 2013 14:00:00'),
> "logEvent": 2,
> "logMessage": "Success!"
> } )

With an index on `expireAt` field.
I have as input a `int` that represents the time since epoch in milliseconds and I need to create the above date.

How can I build such date with `datetime` and `pymongo` from a `millisSinceEpoch` integer?

I have found many answers but I have no idea if the `TTL` index will work with any date format different than the one shown above (from the documentation).

Comment: thanks for your comment. However i can't use anything else than ```python``` because my code is running in a Lambda function in AWS, with python 3.9 runtime.

Comment: Check [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your timestamp using `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`, bearing in mind this takes an input in *seconds*. You may need to divide by 1,000 to get milliseconds.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp

Sample code, converts to and from POSIX timestamp:

```
import pymongo
import datetime

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client['mydatabase']

dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

ts = dt.timestamp()
print(ts)

db.mycollection.insert_one({'date': datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)})

print(list(db.mycollection.find({'date': dt}, {'_id': 0})))
```

prints:

```
1635066038.917683
[{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 24, 10, 0, 38, 917000)}]
```